# Why must I initialize variables in a class?

Tags: ruby, initialization, attr-accessor

I am in the process of learning the new Ruby language and am a little confused as to why all variables must be initialized.

I would think that the `attr_accessor` method would cover this.  It seems redundant to do both.  Does the `attr_accessor` not assume that the variable is global?

Any help in explaining this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Variables don't "have to be initialized" at all. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to initialize anything.

If you think about the "initialize" method:

```
class People
attr_accessor :name,:age,:sex
  def initialize(name,age,sex)
    @name = name
    @sex = sex
    @age = age
   end
end
```

It's a construct you chose to do, when creating classes and organize your app. This method (`initialize`) will be executed when you call the `new` method for People: `People.new`.

`attr_accessor` gives you a setter and getter with meta-programing, meaning you don't need to type a lot of code.

Below is an example of a getter method, commonly known as a "reader", elegantly replaced with `attr_reader`:

```
def name
  @name = name
end
```

And the corresponding setter method, also known as a "writer" using `attr_writer`:

```
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end
```

Both setter and getter you can use with `attr_accessor`. Perhaps I digressed, but I wanted to explain the concept as I understood it since it seems you didn’t understand it well.

Short answer is, you don’t need to initialize anything if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps quite a bit.  Like I said I am new to all this.  I appreciate you taking thing time to reply

Comment: No problem man, keep learning, don’t quit, pick a book and keep with t it. I would suggest Well Ground Rubiest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean instance variables defined in a class?

If so, defining them in `def initialize` ensures that each object of the class is created with the appropriate variables.

attr_accessor can then be used to add read/write methods for each of the variables.

`def initialize` does not automatically add the read/write methods because not all variables should have them (e.g., an `id` would likely have a read method, but probably not a write method).